# A simple check of double precision agreement using trigonometric functions

Tags: fortran

This behavior caught my eye the other day:

```
PROGRAM Sine
  USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_Fortran_env, dp=>REAL64 !modern DOUBLE PRECISION
  IMPLICIT NONE
  REAL(dp), PARAMETER :: PI = 3.1415926535897931 !PRINT *, ACOS(-1.0D+00)
  PRINT *, SIN(PI / 4.0_dp)
  PRINT *, COS(PI / 4.0_dp)
  PRINT *, SQRT(2.0_dp) / 2.0_dp
END PROGRAM Sine
```

Unformatted output gives **0.7071067**9664085752, **0.7071067**6573223719, and **0.7071067**8118654757, respectively. I don’t understand why this doesn’t agree to double precision: `SQRT(2.0D+00) / 2.0D+00` is exact, while `SIN(PI / 4.0D+00)` and `COS(PI / 4.0D+00)` should come from the Taylor series for those functions. I can get slightly better agreement out of a pocket calculator, so clearly I'm doing something wrong. Replacing the above intrinsic functions with `DSIN`, `DCOS`, and `DSQRT` produces the same result--though I wouldn't expect any different. Does anyone understand why this is happening?

Comment: Your PI is not double precision. That was shown here many many times.

Comment: Also here, on different site https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/910/how-to-set-double-precision-values-in-fortran and a whole discussion https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.fortran/IoI5Mes2Se4